# Refresh JWT Token in Laravel when blacklist is enabled

Tags: laravel, jwt

I have to refresh the token when its expired. But it doesn't allow me when blacklist is enabled.

**Below is the code in jwt.php file**

```
# Testing Purpose so kept small

'ttl' => 10,
'refresh_ttl' => 600,
'blacklist_enabled' => env('JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED', true),
```

**For Creating Token**

```
$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user_obj);
```

**For refreshing Token (fails when blacklist_enabled is set to true)**

```
public function refreshToken()
{
   $token = JWTAuth::getToken();

   if(!$token)
      return Response::json(['error' => 'Token not provided'], 403);

   try {
      $token = JWTAuth::refresh($token);
   } catch (TokenInvalidException $e) {
      return Response::json(['error' => 'Session Expired'],401);
   }

   return Response::json(compact('token'));
}
```

I have seen issues discussed here

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/83

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1160

but not getting solution for it. Can someone please let me know

Comment: can someone reply...

Comment: Hoping for a solution too as I am encountering this error as well.

Comment: @basagabi still i waiting

Comment: @Sharath Hey, did you found solution? I'm looking for it also.

Comment: @М.Б.  no i haven't...

Comment: @Sharath if you are still intersted in, i can share solution whose i just found.

Comment: @М.Б. please share, actually I have just kept the concept on hold on working on other things... So if u share i can check it out

Comment: @Sharath I'm currently very in а crowd. But if it's urgent to you, i will send it asap.

Comment: Once you get time, please sent it without fail.... or you can post the answer here so that it might help others...

Comment: @Sharath i will :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how i get refreshing done:

In `AuthController` i have method:

```
public function patchRefresh()
{
    $current_token  = JWTAuth::getToken();
    $token          = JWTAuth::refresh($current_token);

    return response()->json([
        "status" => "success",
        "code" => 200,
        'data' =>
            compact('token'),
        'messages' => ['Token refreshed!'],
    ]);
}
```

In my case, i have Front-end - Back-end - API architecture. So, on front-end i send before every request AJAX to back-end, to take token from session and send request to API (via curl), also, `Authorization` header with token need to be included.

This is how it's looks like:

### Front-end:

```
function tryToRefreshToken() {
    try {
        var message;
        var noToken = false;


        var response = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async:false,
            url: api + "?action=refresh-token",
            success: function (response) {}
        }).responseText;

        response = JSON.parse(response);

        if ( response  ){
            message = response.messages[0];
            if (message.indexOf("no token") > -1 || message.indexOf("Expired") > -1 || message.indexOf("absent") > -1) {
                noToken = true;
            }else if (message.indexOf("Refreshed")){
                console.log("Token refreshed!");
            }else{
                console.log(message);
            }
        }else{
            console.log("No response");
        }

        if (noToken) {
            console.log("There is no valid token!");
            alert("Your session is expired... Please, login to continue. ");
                logout();
                loadNavbar();
                loadMainContent();
            }

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}
```

### Back-end:

```
    if ( !isset($_SESSION['token']) ){
        echo Helper::onFail(401,["There is no token provided."]);
        return;
    }

    $account_id = $_SESSION['account']['id'];
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user']['id'];

    if ( empty($user_id) || empty($account_id)){
        echo Helper::onFail(401,["There is no User or Account id provided!"]);
        return;
    }

    $url = API_ORIGIN . "api/auth/refresh";
    $headers = Helper::getHeaderAuth();
    $response = Helper::patchRequest($url,null, $headers);

//        echo json_encode($response, true); break;

    try{
        $message = "empty";

        if (isset($response['messages'])){
            $message = $response['messages']['0'];
        }else{
            $message = $response['message'];
        }

            if ( stristr($message,"expired") || stristr($message,"invalid") || stristr($message,"not create")){
                Helper::log("Message: " . $message);
                echo Helper::onFail(401, ["Expired"]);  // write

            }else if (stristr($message, "refreshed")){
                $_SESSION['token'] = trim($response['data']['token']);
                echo Helper::onSuccess($response['data']['token'], ["Refreshed"]);
                Helper::log("Refreshed token: " . implode(" ", $response['data']['token']));

            }else{

                Helper::log("Message: {$message}");
            }

    }catch (Exception $exception) {
        Helper::log("Exception: " . $exception->getMessage());
        echo Helper::onFail(401, [$exception->getMessage()]);
    }
```

There are methods used:

```
/**
 * Perform Patch request via cURL
 * @param $url
 * @param $data
 * @param array $headers
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function patchRequest($url, $data, array $headers=[])
{
    $fields_string = "";

    //url-ify the data for the POST
    foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return json_decode($data,true);

}


public static function getHeaderAuth()
{
    return ["Accept: application/json", "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" , "Authorization: Bearer " . $_SESSION['token'] ];
}
```

On API, `patchRefresh` method gets old token and generate new token which have new expiration time. And then, i replace old token with new one in session. So, if user get inactive for ex. one hour and if TTL of token is one hour, he will be redirected to login. If token is not expired, with every request it will be renewed.